# Get the same font size in overleaf figures as overleaf text

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, seaborn, overleaf

I am writing a report in Overleaf where I use a font-size of 12px. I have some SVG figures that I have created in python where I use figure size

```
plt.Figure(figsize=(16, 14))
```

and I set the font size using seaborn to be

```
seaborn.set(font_scale=12/10)
```

to include the figures in overleaf I use

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \centerline{\includesvg[inkscapelatex=false,width=0.75\columnwidth]{Figures/fig1.svg}}
    \caption{figure caption}
    \label{fig:fig1}
    \end{figure}
```

But the text does not become the same size as the text in overleaf. How can I make the text (labels, legends, ticks) in the python figures to be the same size as the text in overleaf? I do not want the figures to be to big in overleaf.

EDIT:
this is the document setup:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,10pt,b5paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,tmargin=27mm,bmargin=30mm]{geometry}
```

Comment: I'm skeptical that `0.75\columnwidth` is equal to 16 inches, which is the size of the figure you are making.  Figure out `\columnwidth` and then make `figsize` match

Comment: I guess it is not. I just made them pretty big in python and the plan was to just scale them down in Overleaf. I added the document margin setup.

Comment: So your figure is 99 mm wide.  If you want the figure to be 99 mm wide, set `figsize=(99 / 25.4, 99 / 25.4 * 14 / 16)`